# Margin does not workk

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have this section that is not centered so I thought that I need margin-left but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas how I can fix it?

[This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kPqc.jpg)

This is the code:

```css
.margins {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row margins">

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/AnonymousCode/anonymouscode.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/AC_324x400-1.jpg"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">ANONYMOUS; CODE</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/CHAOS;HEAD NOAH/CHAOS;HEAD NOAH.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/CHN_324x400.png"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">CHAOS;HEAD NOAH</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/CHAOS DOUBLE PACK/CHAOSDOUBLEPACK.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/CHC_324x400.jpg"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">CHAOS;HEAD NOAH / DOUBLE PACK</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/AI-nirvana/ai_nirvana.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/AI2_324x400_r2.jpg"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">AI: THE SOMNIUM FILES</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use `display: flex` and `align-items : center` for the margin div? can you elaborate more your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

No need for margins, use Bootstrap's `d-flex justify-content-center` classes on the row.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row margins d-flex justify-content-center">

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/AnonymousCode/anonymouscode.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/AC_324x400-1.jpg"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">ANONYMOUS; CODE</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/CHAOS;HEAD NOAH/CHAOS;HEAD NOAH.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/CHN_324x400.png"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">CHAOS;HEAD NOAH</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/CHAOS DOUBLE PACK/CHAOSDOUBLEPACK.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/CHC_324x400.jpg"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">CHAOS;HEAD NOAH / DOUBLE PACK</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 my-3">
    <a href="/AI-nirvana/ai_nirvana.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.spike-chunsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/AI2_324x400_r2.jpg"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center">AI: THE SOMNIUM FILES</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```